# Magento CSS and JS in head including from document root?

Tags: php, apache, magento

I have just set up a new server running ubuntu and all the latest versions of apache mysql and php, also with all the necessary extensions for running Magento.

I've transferred my test site across to the new server and everything works accept styles and scripts, for some reason they are including from the document root (/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/), the strange thing is it seems only the js and css added using XML is wrong.

I've checked the core_config_data table and the urls are correct, all file permissions are correct safe mode is off memory_limits etc have been checked.

Could this have something to do with the apache2 setup?

Comment: Thanks Nick, but the problem still persists even after clearing all caches

Answer (score 9):

This has to do with the fact that you have enabled CSS/JS merging, but Magento doesn't have sufficient access rights to write the merged files to media/css and media/js.

> chmod o+w -R media

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried opening permissions for the whole application. It's still including from the doc root. I restarted the server and it worked for about 30 minutes now doing it again.

Comment: On Mac OSX Mavericks from Magento Document root...

    rm -rf ./var/cache/*
    chmod -R o+w media